# Reviewing source of DNS requests

Tags: bind, domain-controller, forwarding, domain-name-system

Is there a way to know the source of DNS requests which were handed to the Forwarder (requests which were handled by the DC are of no interest)?

If I set up a BIND server which is a forwarder to the DC, in the BIND logs I will only see the Dc as the request source, and not the host itself which made the request.

Is there a way to do so instead of digging through the huge log files of the DC?

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer is no. There's some discussion of this at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5991370/401590

Comment: There is a draft for a DNS extension, which might help here. But I have no idea if the software you are using supports it: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-vandergaast-edns-client-subnet-02

Comment: The current draft version is actually https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-vandergaast-dnsop-edns-client-subnet-00, from what I can tell.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Looks like you are right. Now I am left wondering why the expired version doesn't have a link to the current version.

Comment: @kasperd For whatever reason the draft name has changed at least twice during the draft process. It started out at http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-vandergaast-edns-client-ip-00, continued at http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-vandergaast-edns-client-subnet-00 and then continued at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-vandergaast-dnsop-edns-client-subnet-00

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I seem to recall having seen links between the different names when a draft was renamed during the process. But I cannot find such links on this particular draft.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the resolver server used by these clients implements the draft spec for [Client Subnet in DNS Requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-vandergaast-dnsop-edns-client-subnet-00), which embeds the client address information in the query dns message, there is no way to know the address of the original client at any point after that.

However, even if you do have a server that implements the draft specification for this, the idea is that one should not include the full client address but at most the /24 prefix (or shorter prefix if that makes sense) for IPv4 and some similar, yet unspecified, strategy for IPv6 (presumably a prefix shorter than /64 should be included).